# WiX: incomplete shortcut to command prompt

Tags: windows, batch-file, wix, windows-installer, wix3.7

I have the following shortcut definition:

```xml
<Directory Id="TARGETDIR" Name="SourceDir">
    <Directory Id="ProgramFiles64Folder">
        <Directory Id="INSTALLFOLDER" Name="InGenius">
            <Directory Id="APPLICATIONFODLER" Name="ICE Publisher" />
        </Directory>
    </Directory>
    <Directory Id="ProgramMenuFolder">
        <Directory Id="CompanyFolder" Name="InGenius">
            <Directory Id="AppFolder" Name="ICE Publisher" />
        </Directory>
    </Directory>
</Directory>
<DirectoryRef Id="AppFolder">
  <Component Id="ApplicationShortcut" Guid="*">
    <Shortcut Id="ApplicationStartMenuShortcut"
              Name="App CMD Prompt"
              Target="[SystemFolder]CMD.exe"
              Arguments="/K [APPLICATIONFOLDER]app.bat"
              WorkingDirectory="APPLICATIONFOLDER"
              Show="normal"/>
    <RemoveFolder Id="CompanyFolder" Directory="CompanyFolder"
                  On="uninstall" />
    <RemoveFolder Id="AppFolder" On="uninstall" />
    <RegistryValue Root="HKCU" 
                   Key="Software\Microsoft\InGenius ICE Publisher" 
                   Name="installed" Type="integer" Value="1" KeyPath="yes" />
  </Component>
</DirectoryRef>
```

I get a shortcut with the following target:

`C:\Windows\SysWOW64\cmd.exe /K app.bat`

And nothing in the `Start in:` field.

I was expecting a target of:

`C:\Windows\SysWOW64\cmd.exe /K c:\ProgramFiles\appfolder\app.bat`

and have

`c:\ProgramFiles\appfolder\app.bat`

in the `Start in:` field

What did I do wrong?

Comment: Well, for the life of me, after lots of fiddling, I can't see what I changed but it's now working. :-|

Answer (score 2):

Looks like APPLICATIONFOLDER property is not set. Check its value in debug log and set the value of APPLICATIONFOLDER property before installation starts.

Comment: I updated the code snippet to include the definitions I have for my directories.  They seem fine to me and the application does get installed in the correct folder.  The shortcut definitely ends up looking as if APPLICATIONFOLDER was not defined.